# SQL-Server-2008: XML Question

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008

I am wondering how to obtain the following from a query using xml on sql server 2008.

I need:

```
1. The XML Version
2. The xmlns
3. And one parent node called "Brand" containing many child nodes called "Name"
```

Also I tried ...`For XML Auto` but that give me the node

```
<Brands Name="nameofBrand">
```

Instead I need

```
<Brand><Name>nameofbrand</Name></Brand>
```

EDIT:

The query is quite simple for now....

```
Select Distinct
    Name
From
    Brands
For XML AUTO
```

Comment: What do you actually have in your database?  is it an `XML` column?  What's your query?  What columns are in the `Brands` table?

Comment: Name(varchar), Status(bit), BBFKid(int)

Comment: Do you want `<Brands><Brand><Name>Coke</Name></Brand><Brand><Name>Pepsi</Name></Brand></Brands>` or `<Brand><Name>Coke</Name><Name>Pepsi</Name></Brand>`?

Comment: Yes, i'd like the <version><xmlns><Brand><name>name</name></Brand><brand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that gets a name list in brands node. I do not understand what you want to do with version or xmlns.

```
select (
  select distinct Name
  from YourTable for xml path(''), type)
for xml path('Brands')
```